# Writing a simple program in Spark 1.4.0

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new in Spark. I installed jdk8 and eclipse (mars) in debian 8. And installes Spark1.4.0 and used sbt/sbt assembly command to get all required. COuld anyone tell me how to write a simple hello program in spark using eclipse ide which need to coded in java. or tell me a url to do the same. I need a step-by-step help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a maven project and add spark 1.4 maven dependency as follow.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And start coding in eclipse ide.
you can follow [this](http://blog.knoldus.com/2014/06/04/a-simple-application-in-spark-and-scala/) or [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-run-a-simple-apache-spark-app-in-cdh-5/) and [here](https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/mini-complete-example/src/main/java/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/mini/java/WordCount.java) is the java wordcount in spark example code

The link is for scala, but the same goes for java. hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you. And I have a doubt whether the maven package is come along with the spark, or does we install it seperatly?

Comment: you need to install eclipse maven plugin and create new maven project from file wizard. check it may be already installed in your eclipse

Comment: Is it necessary that JAVA_HOME, SCALA_HOME,MAVEN_HOME all in same path?

Comment: No dear, it is not necessary